# Need two different styles for two different implementations of CSS nav[role="navigation"] on the same page

Tags: html, css

I am using `nav[role="navigation"]` in two different places on one page (side nav and footer nav).

I simply want to style the footer nav differently to the side nav but I can't work out How to do so using CSS.

**First Use:** (you can see I hoped that by providing an "id" attribute I could style it that way...)

```
<section class="links">
  <nav role="navigation" id="inpage">
    <ul>
      <li>
         <h2><a href="http://www.site.uk/contact/">Contact us</a></h2>
         <p>Find details of how to contact us.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

**Second Use**

```
<nav role="navigation" id="navigation" aria-label="Navigation">
  <div class="inner">
    <h6>About</h6>
      <ul class="about">
        <li><a href="/about/">About this site</a></li>
        <li><a href="/accessibility/">Accessibility</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav[role="navigation"] {
 background-color: #000 !important;
 height:100%;
}

nav[role="navigation"] h2 {
 border: none;
}

#navigation .inner ul li {
 display: block;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative
}
```

The issue is that this naturally styles both uses of `nav[role="navigation"]`.

I simply wish to make the `background #e0e0e0` for the instance of nav where I have added the 'id' and for it not to be #000 as in the second instance.

Using the CSS of:

```
#inpage {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Makes no difference.

Must be simple.

Many thanks.

Comment: you have different ids for the 2 navs, why not use those ids for the selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just stick to putting the styles that are shared between them in `nav[role="navigation"]`. For everything else just do:

```
nav#inpage {
  ..
}

nav#navigation {
  ..
}
```

Comment: Ah. Yes! Perfect! Much obliged to you.